# perform sum on column containing multiple values without splitting the values into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

**df:**

```
    k   val
0   1   1,3
1   1   1,5
2   2   1,6
3   1   4,5
4   2   5,7
5   3   8,9
```

**expected output:**

```
    k   val
0   1   6,13
1   2   6,13
2   3   8,9
```

Explantion:

groupby them by `k` and take sum of 1st elements and 2nd elements

```
k   val
1   1,3   
1   1,5  #-----> 1   (1+1+4), (3+5+5)
1   4,5  #-----> 1   6,13

2   1,6  #-----> 2   (1+5), (6+7)
2   5,7  #-----> 2   6,13 

3   8,9  #-----> 3   8,9
```

Can I groupby and sum them together without splitting them into 2 columns and then joining the result?

This is what I have done:

```
df[['val1', 'val2']] = df['val'].str.split(",", expand=True)
df['val1'] = df['val1'].astype(int)
df['val2'] = df['val2'].astype(int)
(df.groupby('k').agg({'val1':'sum', 'val2': 'sum'})
 .apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(x['val1']), str(x['val2'])]), axis=1)
 .reset_index(name='val'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you still need split, convert to integers, sum, convert to strings and join:

```
f = lambda x:  ','.join(map(str, [sum(map(int, z)) 
                                  for z in (zip(*[y.split(',') for y in x]))]))
df = df.groupby('k')['val'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   k   val
0  1  6,13
1  2  6,13
2  3   8,9
```

Your solution:

```
df = (df['val'].str.split(",", expand=True).astype(int)
               .groupby(df['k'])
               .sum()
               .astype(str)
               .agg(','.join, 1)
               .reset_index(name='val'))
print (df)
   k   val
0  1  6,13
1  2  6,13
2  3   8,9
```

Comment: Which one do you think is better one : 1st or second solution?

Comment: @Pygirl - I think depends of data, only guess first should be faster (best test in real data)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `apply`:

```
val = df.groupby('k')['val'].apply(lambda x: f"{x.str.split(',', expand=True)[0].astype(int).sum()}, {x.str.split(',', expand=True)[1].astype(int).sum()}").tolist()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'k': df['k'].drop_duplicates().tolist(), 'val': val})
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    k     val
0   1   6, 13
1   2   6, 13
2   3   8, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel if you are not using Pandas' built in tools, then native python should be faster. Of course, only tests can affirm or deny that. Just my personal experience.

The solution I proffer uses [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and builds a new dataframe :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

grouped = zip(df.k, df.val)
for key, value in grouped:
    # split looks unavoidable
    value = [int(num) for num in value.split(",")]
    d[key].append(value)

d = [
    (key, ",".join(f"{sum(entry)}" for entry in zip(*value)))
    for key, value in d.items()
]
pd.DataFrame(d, columns=df.columns)

    k   val
0   1   6,13
1   2   6,13
2   3   8,9
```